# Adding 1 of 2 php groups to index.php on Wordpress breaks the page, I can have either or

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an index.php file that works fine if:

```
<?php if (is_page()) { ?>
    <?php the_post();the_content(); ?>

    <h4>RECENT POSTS:</h4>
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?> 
    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=3' ); ?>
    <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li></h4>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?></p>
```

```
<?php }?>
```

Which displays the recent posts at the bottom of the page. But I want to make those posts thumbnails:

```
    <?php 
$thumbnails = get_posts( 'numberposts=5' );
foreach ( $thumbnails as $thumbnail ) {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail->ID ) ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail->post_title ) . '">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail->ID, 'thumbnail' );
        echo '</a>';
    }
}
?>
```

Which works fine! But there's no content, because I've left out the

```
<?php if (is_page()) { ?>
    <?php the_post();the_content(); ?>
```

When I add that, and it becomes

```
<?php if (is_page()) { ?>
    <?php the_post();the_content(); ?>
<?php 
$thumbnails = get_posts( 'numberposts=5' );
foreach ( $thumbnails as $thumbnail ) {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail->ID ) ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail->post_title ) . '">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail->ID, 'thumbnail' );
        echo '</a>';
    }
}
?>
```

Which breaks the page/displays blank white for that page. (home page)

Is there something with that code in particular? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After cleaning up your code to remove extra bits and formatting it nicely, we have this:

```
<?php
if (is_page()) {
    the_post();
    the_content();
    $thumbnails = get_posts('numberposts=5');
    foreach ($thumbnails as $thumbnail) {
        if (has_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID)) {
            echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail->post_title ) . '">';
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail->ID, 'thumbnail' );
            echo '</a>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Now that the code is clearer, you can see that there's a missing closing brace at the bottom, for the original `if` statement.  The following code should work:

```
<?php
if (is_page()) {
    the_post();
    the_content();
    $thumbnails = get_posts('numberposts=5');
    foreach ($thumbnails as $thumbnail) {
        if (has_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID)) {
            echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail->post_title ) . '">';
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail->ID, 'thumbnail' );
            echo '</a>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Remember, `<?php` gets you into PHP land, and `?>` takes you back out.  If you have something like `<?php echo 'Foo!'; ?> <?php echo 'Bar!'; ?>` that middle part can be safely taken out, as it's all PHP in there: `<?php echo 'Foo!'; echo 'Bar!'; ?>`  This helps clarify things and makes troubleshooting easier.

Another thing that will help you out a lot if configuring PHP to spit out errors somewhere, such as an error.log on your server, which you can then consult for details about what might be going wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much Justin, this fixed it! Thank you for the explanation as well.